# Django rest framework endpoints and passing the values

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

i am very new to Django and REST. I started working with rest-auth recently just to explore.
Can someone explain me, what does this mean and how do i pass the values.

```
rest-auth/ ^password/reset/$[name='rest_password_reset']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you incorrectly posted code example. This looks like a rout (the part before and including `$` sign) and another part is a [url pattern name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for this rout (for [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method, for example).

This is a default rout for password reset in django-rest-auth frameword. You can make a `POST` request to [pass email there](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#basic)

Comment: Thanks Charnel, it helped